# stackOverflow UI design secrets?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, styling

I am sure all of you have observed the cohesive design of this site. My question is about some of the cool info-boxes...that appear on various events. Like when someone with lower reputation tries to down-vote OR the long box that appears just below the browser address bar when I have got response to one of my questions.

These are basically JS  generated DIV elements...but do any one of you know a good library/ set of controls that can be used to achieve these styling effects?

Comment: Better move this to meta.stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: No, this is not a meta discussion, it's a UI design question, that happened to use SO as an example.

Comment: I don't know, but I, for one, would like SO more if it didn't.  If I'm browsing, I want to just browse, thanks, and I'll check my messages later.  At best, this is merely a slightly less awful use of push on the web than most.

Comment: Its not meta - the OP just using an example site to demonstrate their requirements, it just happen to be the same site you are on right now ;-) . Here, I'll retag it to show you what I mean.

Comment: Also moved to meta discussion.

Comment: Many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stackoverflow%20[jquery]&tab=relevance

Answer (score 16):

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/) [can](http://www.noupe.com/jquery/50-amazing-jquery-examples-part1.html) [do](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/51-best-of-jquery-tutorials-and-examples.html) [a lot](http://www.noupe.com/ajax/37-more-shocking-jquery-plugins.html) [of](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/23/50-useful-new-jquery-techniques/) [nice](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/09/16/jquery-examples-and-best-practices/) [things](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/15/45-new-jquery-techniques-for-a-good-user-experience/)

Comment: Thats a generic library...I am looking for something pre-defined...with which I can hit the ground running.

Comment: You can't get much simpler than jQuery to be honest. 

$("body").append("<div class="notice">You did something!</div>");

Answer (score 3):

[JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is the obvious first answer :)

Comment: Welcome to the JQuery cult. Actually Glow (http://bbc.com/glow) is a much better answer as it offers methods for animation and UI control that JQuery does not, but both are not a good answer for the OP

Answer (score 3):

> do any one of you know a good library/ set of controls that can be used to achieve these styling effects?

What styles are you talking about? Everything in SO is essentially a normal html box (div) with borders, margins, and padding, and other plain and simple css settings.

There's no fancy widget anywhere, at least not something that I can see.

In fact, it's quite ugly, but we programmers have no taste :)

We like it because it's simple and straight to the point, not because it looks fancy.

Comment: Simple and straight to the point?  I thought that was USENET!  SO has big full-color avatars, arrows and stars and badges, ajax search and textboxes, and fancy text formatting, in addition to the fancy alerts asked about here.  Or as pg once said, "It takes a surprising amount of work to make it look like the site has no design".

Comment: @Alec: Yes, all this is awesome functionality, but there are no "styling effects". It's all very basic css stuff. color, background-color, font, border, padding, margin. e.g. red box with white text in it, wow, fancy widgets eh?

Answer (score 0):

And yes I know the WZ library...which is pretty cool. But am looking for something more cohesive and closer in resemblance to stackOverflow styling.

http://www.walterzorn.com/

Comment: this link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) will do what you want... just use it to insert a div. If you want more widget-ey type things there's also [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/).

Answer (score 0):

As eveyone said [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) is there in Stackoverflow doing some animations :)

if you see in the view source ,You can find out ,how it is working

E.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Few days back i had  same doubt .I researched on it and got some of nice animations as like stackoverflow using [Jquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jquery).